# Perforce: what's the difference between a revert and a forced sync?

Tags: perforce

What is the difference between these two commands, if any:

```
# revert my file to the revision last synced from the depot
p4 revert test.c

# force synchronization to refresh file and discard pending changes
p4 sync -f test.c
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your scenario, the commands are similar, but:

1. `revert` will only revert a file that is currently marked as open; `sync -f` will only overwrite a file that is NOT open.
2. `revert` requires a file pattern as an argument, `sync -f` does not.
3. `sync -f` causes the server to send you a new copy of the file even if your current copy is unmodified, and is thus somewhat a waste of computer time and network resources.

There are other differences, but they seem less important for your scenario.

In my opinion, the nicest way to return a workspace to its unmodified state is actually to use `p4 clean`, which was added to the server in release 2014.1. Here's a nice writeup about the `clean` command: https://www.perforce.com/blog/140501/p4-clean-make-workspace-shine

For other alternatives, see this related question: [Perforce fast sync a directory to a clean state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814832/perforce-fast-sync-a-directory-to-a-clean-state)

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe `p4 sync -f` will discard your pending local changes. Use `p4 revert`.

Comment: 'sync -f' will overwrite the file if it is NOT open for edit, thus discarding your pending local changes.

Comment: Sure. I assumed it was opened for edit, since carmellose is asking about `p4 revert`.